# Is there any pattern to the order customization pieces unlock?

Tags: mario-kart-8

As was mentioned in [another answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/169982/24756), vehicle customization pieces in *Mario Kart 8* unlock by collecting coins; with intervals of 50-100 set as criteria.

However, it seems that while the manner of unlocking items is stable, what you receive is not. For example: The unlock guides provided by [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mario-kart-8/Unlockables#Unlockable_Karts_and_Parts) and [Gamers Heroes](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/mario-kart-8-guide-coin-unlockables-coins-unlock/) both claim that the [Yoshi Bike](http://www.mariowiki.com/Yoshi_Bike) is awarded at `600` coins. However, although I have already collected more than `600` coins (from the unlock messages, I estimate I'm approaching the `1400` mark), I still have yet to receive the bike in question. Other players around the internet seem to have similar situations to mine; for example: [this comment](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/mario-kart-8-guide-coin-unlockables-coins-unlock/#comment-1418238420) by Sharon.

I have also heard mention that perhaps the vehicle customizations' unlock order is random, the class of item you recieve isn't. For example, at the `600` coin mark *some* sort of bike would be unlocked, not necessarily a *specific* one. I can't find any information directly in favor or against this rumor.

So in short, is there any rhyme or reason to the order in which vehicle customization pieces are unlocked? and if so, what the heck is it! :)

Answer (score 3):

On the [IGN page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mario-kart-8/Unlockables#Unlockable_Karts_and_Parts) you linked it says "Vehicle customization parts **unlock randomly**". I've confirmed that mine are not unlocked on the order of that page.