# How do I get the Golden Kart pieces?

Tags: mario-kart-8

I really want the Golden Kart, I already have the the Golden Glider, how do you get the other two pieces, if there is, are there any other ways to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many coins do I need to unlock all the kart pieces?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169980/how-many-coins-do-i-need-to-unlock-all-the-kart-pieces)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.This question refers to the Golden Cart pieces without reference to coins. To a newcomer who might not know about the coin requirement this is a very different question than "how many coins do I need". And besides, this question encompasses other ways of unlocking the pieces.

Comment: Thanks for backing me up on this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-06-02-mario-kart-8-deluxe-unlockables-gold-mario-gold-kart-parts-4623):  to get the GoldenKart, you need to "win every Cup with a single star on both 150cc and Mirror Mode in Grand Prix."

So, it looks like you've got a lot of races ahead of you!

If you are also looking to get the gold tires, that site tells you you have to "Beat every Staff Ghost in Time Trial mode at 150cc."

Comment: Thanks, that really helped a lot!

Comment: What are the Staff ghosts?